# jQuery click + if + .find function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Going nuts here.

Trying to write a function where if there's a '.child' class element inside the container, the function fires, but otherwise does nothing.

However, using .find() (as it's not a direct child) doesn't seem to do anything.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu-box li').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-box li').find('.child')) {
      showContent($(this));

      function showContent(elem) { // Add open classes when sub menu clicked
        hideContent();
        elem.find('.content').addClass('expanded');
        elem.addClass('cover');
      }

      function hideContent() { // Remove open classes when sub menu closed
        $('.menu-box .content').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.menu-box li').removeClass('cover');
      }
      $('.menu-box .sub-menu').append('<span class="close left-arrow"></span>'); // Add close button to sub menu
      $('.menu-box .close').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        hideContent();
      }); // Close sub menu on click
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mega-menu inner_container">

  <div class="menu-box">
    <!-- item without any children -->
    <li>
      <span class="parent title">Parent title</span>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="inner_container sub-menu">
          <span class="parent title">Parent title</span>
          <ul class="two-col"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-box">
    <!-- item with children -->
    <li>
      <span class="parent title">Parent title</span>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="inner_container sub-menu">
          <span class="parent title">Parent title</span>
          <ul class="two-col">
            <li><span class="child title">Child title</span></li>
            <li><span class="child title">Child title</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span class="child title">Child title</span></li>
    <li><span class="child title">Child title</span></li>
    <li><span class="child title">Child title</span></li>
    <li><span class="child title">Child title</span></li>
  </div>

</ul>
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. Been tweaking it for about 5 hours and just can't get it to work.

Comment: try adding `.length` to it - `if ($('.menu-box li').find('.child').length)`

Comment: Pete is correct. `.find()` always returns an jQuery object, which is never null.

Comment: Hmm, it's still firing on elements without children unfortunately :(

Comment: `$(".menu-box li").find()` is searching all menu boxes, not the one you clicked on. Use `$(this).find()`

Comment: On a side note, the script can definitely be optimized.